# Import stock price from Yahoo Finance into R?

Tags: r, import, currency, yahoo

I want to to import the currency close price from Yahoo finance or Oanda into R.

I tried to follow the same steps as mentioned in similar  question: 
[Import stock price from Yahoo Finance into R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/import-stock-price-from-yahoo-finance-into-r)

But I am receiving NA data instead

```
getQuote("EUR/USD", what=yahooQF("Last Trade (Price Only)"))

Trade         Time Last
EUR/USD       <NA>  N/A
```

Would appreciate any advises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("EUR=X",src="yahoo")
```